# Anonymous Users to view PRODUCTS

Tags: commerce

I have enabled "View all products product" -- I have disabled sql rewriting.

Although I still cannot get anonymous users to VIEW ANYTHING in the store. Because of the ADMIN overlay?

Comment: Okay. So far. I'm using Commerce_POS
I have the View any products Product -- enabled for all users.

I disabled SQL Rewriting. 

I'm wondering if I need to associate a proper relationship to the "Views" blocks that I am using. -- I associated a relationship to the page using the Forms:tag

Still no luck

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Access denied when viewing a product::
"?q=edibles#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fcommerce%252Fproducts%252F203" 

This site is not live yet, that's why the URL's are not clean. But I don't understand it. I have "Access administer overlays" checked for all roles.

Comment: EXPORT of view::
I cannot export a view in this output -- but here's an example on my website::https://brianwethern.org/content/export-views-improperly-configuring-anonymous-viewers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't very clear on what that permission does vs. how products are displayed. I'm guessing here that you're using Drupal 7. If so, it seems your problem is you're trying to expose the admin paths to products to customers, but those paths aren't intended to be viewed by them. Instead, you're supposed to create either a View that renders product entities directly or a node type with a product reference field on it that functions as what we called a product display. When you attach a product reference field to a node type, it supports embedding product fields into that node while rendering the field itself as an Add to Cart form.

There are a variety of tutorials / guides to understanding and implementing this on the project website: https://drupalcommerce.org

When you need to grant that permission and / or disable SQL rewriting is when you have a View that creates a relationship between your node type (or order line items) to product entities. In that case, though, the View should have additional filters on it to apply appropriate access control so customers only have access to view in that context the products or line items they should.

Comment: Yes, great. You're exactly right. -

But when i tie the product to a relationship. It still does the same thing.

Other than drupalcommerce.org -- Do you know of any good examples? You're on the right path.

Comment: I keep reading how to add product display -- But when I click CREATE A NEW VIEW -- I only get to see::

show: content of type:: basic page or aritcle:: it never lets me choose 

Content :: product display --?

Comment: I don't even have the "Product Display" category undert the content category... Do I have a drupal that nobody else has?

Comment: No, it's just a node like any other. The definition of a "Product Display" is a node type with a product reference field on it. It isn't anything more than that.